# Политика относительно изменения старых вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, модерация, правки

Сейчас на сайте находится большое количество старых вопросов и ответов, оставшихся со времён хэшкода. Многие из них имеют довольно плохое качество. Часто такие вопросы заданы пользователями, активность которых проявлялась один раз.

Многие вопросы можно улучшить, внеся, иногда, довольно *существенные* изменения. Я говорю про изменения, по максимуму оставляющие смысл вопроса прежним, но включающие в себя изменение формулировки вопроса, меток, заголовка, удаление части приведённого кода и т.п.

Насколько есть смысл заниматься подобной деятельностью? Не нарушает ли она правила ресурса?

Возможно, если тема, затронутая в вопросе, действительно была важной, стоит пересоздавать старые вопросы, делая им адекватное оформление и формулировку? Закрывать ли в таком случае старый вопрос, как дубликат, со ссылкой на новый, или предпринимать какое-то другое действие?

По редактированию чужих сообщений есть [статья в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing), но не уверен, что она напрямую применяется к старым сообщениям, так как в то время были, насколько я понимаю, несколько иные правила и критерии качества вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы начал с ответа на следующие вопросы:

1. Вопрос имеет достаточно большое количество просмотров? Если у вопроса, скажем, 1000 или больше просмотров, то это признак того, что вопрос кого-то интересует.
2. Вопрос достаточно полезен широкой публике? Разбор экзотического сочетания условий, приводящего к странной проблеме — вещь, может быть, и интересная, но пользы от неё мало.
3. Ответ высокого качества? Если на на вопрос дан качественный, детальный, всесторонний ответ, то он может быть полезен, даже если вопрос не интересует пользователя напрямую.
4. Вопрос является заброшенным? Не случится ли так, что автор свежего вопроса не узнает свой вопрос?
5. Правка не изменяет полностью смысл вопроса? Полностью изменив вопрос, можно сделать ответы неактуальными.

Если на все вопросы ответ утвердительный, то вносить изменения вполне можно, думаю. Хотя существенные правки и не очень приветствуются (особенно ответов — с этим вообще строго), но при подобном стечении обстоятельств пользы потенциально будет больше, чем вреда.

Comment: Если первый пункт выполняется (вопрос популярен в текущей формулировке), то *не следует вопрос заметно менять* —редактирование может помешать найти этот вопрос людям,  незнакомым с решением. Язык решения может сильно отличаться от языка постановки задачи. Если есть уверенность, что новая формулировка вопроса также будет популярна, то лучше новый вопрос задать. При этом не следует закрывать старый вопрос как дубликат, если старые ответы **без изменений** не применимы к новому вопросу: достаточно ссылку оставить, если вопросы просто похожи.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, если вопрос можно *легко* спасти, не отходя при этом от далеко сути первоначального вопроса, то это должно только приветствоваться. Конечно, желательно при этом, чтобы существующие ответы не теряли своей валидности (то есть, к вопросам с хорошими ответами стоит относиться осторожнее).

Мне кажется, ничего страшного в улучшении кода нет. Возможно, стоит оставить старый код, если только он не *ужасен*. Также заголовки обычно просто нуждаются в освежающей правке (плюс, хороший заголовок позволит вопросу показаться в выдаче поисковиков на релевантном месте).

Если же вопрос не спасти, то лучше задать новый вопрос — особенно если суть вопроса должна быть интересна миру.

---

Чтобы отличить первый случай от второго, пользуйтесь обыкновенным здравым смыслом. Я не думаю, что существуют формальные критерии, чётко различающие спасаемый от неспасаемого вопроса. В крайнем случае воспользуйтесь коллективным разумом — спросите в чате.

Comment: А что по поводу отношения к исходному вопросу при создании нового? Насколько правильно говорить, что дубликатом является старый? Или дубликатом при наличии вариантов всегда помечается менее точный / чётко сформулированный?

Comment: Я бы оставил основным более «качественный» вопрос. Приоритет по времени не играет особой роли.