# Незначительные правки

Tags: обсуждение, правки, правила, предлагаемые-правки

На enSO правки, в которых измененяется только название или только метки, но при этом не улучшаются другие аспекты сообщений, считаются незначительными ("too minor edits") и не приветствуются. 
Ситуации, в которых пользователь вносит большое количество таких правок за непродолжительный период времени часто приводят к "edit ban". Но на ruSO на данный момент такие ситуации в порядке вещей.

Проблемы с наплывом правок [следующие](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309406/how-to-respond-to-a-large-number-of-inconsequential-edits):

- Они выталкивают старые, мало кому интересные сообщения на главную страницу
- Если у пользователя недостаточно репутации, в очередь проверок добавляется множество предлагаемых правок
- Если редактировался закрытый вопрос, он тоже попадает в очередь проверок
- Улучшений тела вопроса не происходит, потому что пользователь сконцентрирован на другой задаче
- Jeff Atwood (создатель StackOverflow) [высказывался](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits) против таких правок
  Предлагаю дополнять список.

Должны ли незначительные правки быть разрешены на ruSO и если должны, то в каких пределах?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Зачем поднимаются старые вопросы с принятыми ответами?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2179/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, [как повлиять?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216198/pavel-bereznichenko?tab=reputation) вся очередь забита проверкой правок удаляющих "Здравствуйте", лишние запятые и прочее, немного раздражает

Comment: @Андрей прямо сейчас забита? Проверю минут через 20.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не прямо сейчас, а в течение дня захожу в очереди проверок и то и дело проверяю как человек удаляет "здрасти", запятые и прочие

Comment: @Андрей ок, я посмотрю. В следующий раз вы можете просто оставить тревогу "для модератора" на любом вопросе, где была правка, которая вам кажется некорректной.

Answer (score 11):

А где грань между "незначительной правкой" и "значительной"?

Если я вижу, что в заголовке вопросы какие-то явные проблемы (банальные проблемы с грамматикой, например), то я исправлю. Как я могу улучшить сам текст сообщения, если, к примеру, я совсем не в теме? Только потому что я не разбираюсь в треде оставить вопрос с явными проблемами в заголовке?

Про метки же... Я часто ищу вопросы по конкретным меткам. На том же enSO специально ищу по каким-то редким, узкоспециализированным меткам. Поэтому приветствую, когда вопросы дополняют актуальными метками, независимо от того, меняют они сам текст вопроса или нет.

Comment: Полностью согласен акромя одного момента - щитаю, что грамматику в заголовках править не надо. Я за грамотность, но и неграмотным (или тем, для кого русский неродной) надо оставить возможность находить чрез поиск результаты даже с очепятками в запросе. ИМХО, конечно же. Как работают поисковые алгоритмы не знаю.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: искать вопросов на Савецки Стековерфлоу очень любовно и прельстиво. Где заголовчек не редактированен, тогда искать очень славно всем забавно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вы утрируете)

Comment: @NickVolynkin поиск на SO и так хреновый. Я обычно через google ищу. А он умеет искать даже по неграмотным заголовкам)

Answer (score 10):

> - *Они выталкивают старые, мало кому интересные сообщения на главную страницу*

Неприятность эту мы переживем, так как у нас есть поиск. Новый дизайн главной страницы (который сейчас обкатывается на en.SO) делает эту проблему еще более несущественной.

В дополнение: [Политика относительно изменения старых вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266/181472)

> - *Если у пользователя недостаточно репутации, в очередь проверок добавляется множество предлагаемых правок*

Это действительно объективная причина для пользователей с репутацией ниже 2000 (1000 в бете). А для пользователей с достаточной репутацией наоборот становятся доступны инструменты для быстрых и частых небольших правок, например [быстрая правка меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Так что от них такие правки всячески приветствуются.

> - *Если редактировался закрытый вопрос, он тоже попадает в очередь проверок*

Цитирую [справку об очередях проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions):

> Любой вопрос, получивший один голос за повторное открытие, добавляется в эту очередь, как и любое сообщение, которое было **отредактировано в течение пяти дней после закрытия вопроса**.

Так что в очередь попадают далеко не все вопросы, а только заданные недавно. Им лишнее внимание не повредит. Например, если была добавлена какая-то метка, то вопрос может увидеть специалист, который эту метку отслеживает.

> - *Улучшений тела вопроса не происходит, потому что пользователь сконцентрирован на другой задаче.*

Это безосновательное утверждение. Вы не можете знать, на чем сконцентрирован другой пользователь и правит ли он тело вопроса. Даже если и нет,

- Может быть он просто добавил метку, так как знает, что вопрос относится к этой метке.
- Или исправил частую ошибку — убрал из заголовка дублирование меток.
- Или убрал мета-метку, вроде [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Любое из этих действий реально улучшает вопрос.

> - *Jeff Atwood (создатель StackOverflow) высказывался против таких правок*

Предлагаю воздержаться от аргументации путем отсылки к авторитетам. Тем более, вы дали ссылку не на статью самого Джеффа, а на другой вопрос на Мете, где кто-то ссылается на мнение Джеффа.

Comment: По-моему, в "Сообщения низкого качества" попадают вопросы и ответы на них после правок.

Comment: @zRrr могут попасть, если очень короткие. Но это с правками не связано, редко правка делает вопрос сильно короче.

Comment: @zRrr: кстати, даже если правка сделала вопрос длиннее, но он остался короче некоторого фиксированного значения, то он все равно попадет в VLQ.