# Допустимы ли мелкие правки?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Вопрос написан по мотивам обсуждения в комментариях к [этому ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4567/14963):

Понятно, что эта тема уже [обсуждалась](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1951/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), и из обсуждения следует что мелкие правки было принято считать допустимыми, но из соседнего обсуждения мне показалось что мнение сообщества по этому поводу могло измениться.

1. Считаются ли допустимыми мелкие улучшающие правки?
2. Если нет, или частично, то что считать мелкой правкой? Необходимо ли требовать в правке исправления всех явных  недостатков вопроса?
3. Если частично, то какие по-вашему ограничения нужно налагать на мелкие правки? Давность вопросов? Количество правок подряд? Еще что-то?

Прошу рассматривать в этом вопросе только явно улучшающие правки, как-то форматирование не форматированного изначально кода, правка орфографических ошибок etc. Вопрос о том является ли улучшающим удаление приветствий здесь не рассматривается.

В частности интересны следующие кейсы:
a). Улучшающая правка метки в очень старом (скажем 2012 год) вопросе. То есть навешивание осмысленной метки явно по теме вопроса.
b). Исправление единичной орфографической ошибки в очень старом вопросе.
c). Пункты a) и b) для множества вопросов (скажем десяти) за короткий промежуток времени.

**UPD:**
d). Корректное исправление пунктационной ошибки в старом вопросе.

Comment: @Grundy, понятно что вопрос уже обсуждался, и мне казалось что мелкие правки однозначно считаются сообществом допустимыми. Но из соседнего обсуждения у меня сложилось мнение что это теперь не так, поэтому я решил поднять этот вопрос снова.

Comment: `Вопрос о том является ли улучшающим удаление приветствий здесь не рассматривается.` - ну всё, обсуждать нечего, расходимся))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этот вопрос касается вопроса с приветствиями косвенно. Вырезание приветствий от Вадима рассматриваемое в вашем вопросе можно считать криминалом как "мелкую правку" и как "неулучшающую правку". Здесь я пытаюсь прояснить насколько состоятельна первая часть обвинения

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, проблема скорее в том, что каждый понимает что-то свое когда говорит: _мелкие правки_ :)

Comment: @Grundy, я специально три юниттеста написал, еще предложите? Кроме того смотри пункт два вопроса. Если же считать любые улучшающие правки допустимыми, то не возникает вопроса "что такое мелкая правка"?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, например, спорные пунктуационные ошибки

Comment: @Grundy, если это исправление пунктуационной ошибки - это улучшающая правка. Если это исправление одного допустимого написания на другое допустимое или недопустимое - это неулучшающая правка.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, например я не всегда сразу могу сказать, правильно ли добавили/удалили запятую и является ли это исправлением допустимого написания, или просто новой ошибкой :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну я тоже. Но в этом вопросе мы не рассматриваем механизм валидации правки на "полезность", лишь механизм валидации правки на "мелкость"

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, я больше к тому, что кто-то мог поправить как ему кажется правильно, а оказалось неправильно :-)

Comment: Еще интересен был бы кейс с исправлением терминологии. Например, меня часто (всегда) тянет исправить слово "кейс" на "случай", "директория" на "каталог" и т.д. В таком случае легко дойти до исправления вида "монитор" -> "экран" или типа того, также многие гуглят _неверно_

Comment: @m9_psy, ваш вопрос обсуждался тут: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2903/it-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82

Comment: @Grundy, да, такое безусловно может быть. Но это "неулучшающая правка". Их я в рамках этого вопроса предлагаю не рассматривать, чтобы не мешать сущностей. Ну то есть я написал этот вопрос чтобы в следующий раз когда кто-то что-то кому-то будет предъявлять, можно было разобрать обвинение по пунктам. Типа "говоришь мои правки мелкие? Ну да, но так, можно." или "ну ок, виноват".

Answer (score 3):

Лично я считаю что мелкие улучшающие правки - допустимы.

В первую очередь, потому что они - полезны.
Искусственное повышение требований к правке на мой взгляд пойдет во вред, потому что не всегда есть время править весь вопрос. А между выбором "править много или не править вообще" многие (в том числе я) выберут не править вообще.

Проблему всплытия старья на главной я считаю не решаемой за счет договоренности об ограничении мелких правок.

Соответственно для кейсов a) b) и c) я считаю все три варианта - допустимыми.
**UPD:** d) также считаю допустимым