# Принимать ли малозначительные правки по добавлению очевидных меток?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

В очереди проверок наткнулся на [эту правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/879036). Её суть в том, что правящий добавляет метку языка ([python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)).

Я уже не первый раз встречаю такие правки. Что с ними делать? С одной стороны, они улучшают сообщение, так как метки языка действительно важны для поиска. С другой стороны, не такие уж они и значительные, <s>немного даже походят на попытку заработать репутацию, ничего особо не делая</s>.

**Обновление:**

Запустил голосование.

Comment: *"С другой стороны .. походят на попытку заработать репутацию, ничего особо не делая."* - внесение правки это дело, и 2 очков точно стоит. А больше 2000 так не заработать всё равно. Так что если человек приучается пользоваться механизмами сайта - это скорее net positive effect.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1953/507426

Comment: @Kromster, а я вот слышал, что в enSO правки изменяющие только заголовок или только метки считаются моветоном и при большом их количестве (как у того, кто предлагал вышеназванную правку) приходит бан на правки на неделю.

Comment: @Глеб всё хорошо в меру. Какие-то массовые незначительные правки и тут порицаются.

Comment: Сам сайт поддерживает такие правки. Если репутации<2000, то при редактировании только метки, ограничения на 6 символов не ставится. Также есть кнопка "править-метки", чтобы менять их не заходя в меню редактирования

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Принимать

Метки языков позволяют производить поиск, и  их добавление — это улучшение сообщения.

Comment: В таком голосовании смысла особого нет, есть устоявшаяся традиция, что правки по добавлению полезных меток допустимы (и приветствуются). Чтобы выносить на голосование, нужно более четкое описание проблемы, почему что-то нужно менять и т.п. Более интересно было бы вынести на голосование отношение к массовым чисткам меток, так как именно это исторически вызывало серьезные драмы.

Answer (score 0):

## Отклонять

Такие правки малозначительные, они слишком мало улучшают сообщение.