# Можно, пожалуйста, я существенно изменю старый вопрос и принятый ответ к нему?

Tags: поддержка

Можно, пожалуйста, я изменю вопрос [Последовательности чисел Фибоначчи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/39229/227016) и принятый ответ к нему? В вопросе удалю весь код и оставлю что-то примерно такое:

> Имеется натуральное число `n`. Как я могу получить первые `n` чисел Фибоначчи?

А из ответа уберу никому не интересный способ вывести первые 11 чисел Фибоначчи и добавлю способы с массивом и с запоминанием последних двух чисел.

Сейчас у вопроса >30000 просмотров. Мне кажется, что почти никому не было интересно, как вывести первые 11 чисел Фибоначчи. Но вопрос звучит именно так и ответ полностью соответствует вопросу. Поэтому если сделать такое изменение, то смысл вопроса существенно изменится. А принятый ответ на [политику относительно изменения старых вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268/227016) не очень приветствует изменять вопросы и особенно ответы.

Comment: По поводу ответа лучше автору написать, он на SO появляется периодически.

Comment: Мне кажется, это отличный ответ. Он показывает, что необязательно всё усложнять и что некоторые значения можно хранить предрассчитанными.

Comment: Расскажите, что вы хотите получить, в чём цель изменений? Если вы хотите сделать образцовый ответ про вычисление последовательности Фибоначчи до N-го члена, задайте сами новый вопрос и дайте на него ответ.

Comment: Почему первые n, а не скажем n-ое число?  Что это у Вас за редакторский бум? Для чего Вы редактируете всё подряд?

Comment: Дались вам эти фиббоначи. Вот тут недавно была война правок, связанная с ними https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/743838/revisions

Answer (score 5):

Я недавно был в похожей ситуации на вашем месте, поэтому хочу поделиться сделанными выводами.

Случается так, что хороший вопрос имеет хорошие ответы, но либо в вопросе либо в ответе есть существенные изъяны, от которых было бы неплохо избавиться. И дописывать свой ответ кажется некорректным, по разным причинам (например, новый ответ полностью повторяет уже существующие, или заимствует из них).

Несмотря на то, что с моей точки зрения многие существующие вопросы и ответы могли бы быть значительно улучшены, мне удалось сформулировать для себя причины, по которым не стоит поддаваться искушению вносить изменения.

- Никогда нет гарантии, что я все понял правильно, и сумел увидеть именно тот формат вопроса и ответа, который увеличит полезность данного поста.
- Внося существенные правки в вопрос или ответ, которому несколько человек отдали свои голоса, я фактически пытаюсь смухлевать и присвоить эти голоса своей точке зрения. Было бы правильнее не менять проверенный временем вопрос или ответ, а создать новый и тоже проверить его временем и узнать настоящее менее сообщества о нем.
- Чем существеннее правка, тем больше риск изменить первоначальные намерения автора.
- Если вопрос или ответ требует существенной правки вплоть до изменения смысла, это скорее признак необходимости создать новый вопрос или ответ.
- Если каждый не будет дисциплинированно придерживаться правила избегать вносить существенные правки без обоснованной необходимости, в конце концов может сложиться такая тенденция поспешно и необдуманно исправлять вопросы и ответы, которая обязательно приведет к массовому допущению ошибочных исправлений и порче вопросов.