# Закрытие вопроса при отсутствии автора на сайте

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690791/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-telegram)

Вопрос был поднят в выдаче Духом сообщества уже в который раз (а чуть ранее был опубликован в Твиттере). Иногда в выдачу попадают вопросы без ответа давностью в несколько лет.

Мой вопрос в том- стоит ли закрывать (выносить на голосование за закрытие/выбор лучшего ответа) данные вопросы, т.к. с большой вероятностью автор вопроса не зайдет на сайт, и вопрос будет постоянно подниматься в выдаче.

**Update:** Недавно был поднят следующий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736935/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-json-array-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82). Как видно, у данного вопроса 2 ответа с положительным рейтингом, соответственно вопрос остается открытым- как предотвратить поднятие Духом подобные вопросы.

Comment: Закрывать точно не за что.
Вопрос, по какому правилу Дух поднимает вопросы?

Comment: @Kromster возможно даже не закрытие, а вынесение на голосование/проверку с целью закрытия/выбора лучшего ответа. Иными словами применения действий при которых вопрос уже не будет подниматься в выдаче Духом.

Comment: @Kromster Дух подымает вопросы, на которые были даны ответы но на ответе нет ни одной оценки (ни одного DV или UV). Увидели такой ответ дайте оценку и его больше никогда не подымет. А закрывать не надо.

Comment: Возможно, связанный [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2?rq=1)

Comment: Еще связанный вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказал A K:

> Дух подымает вопросы, на которые были даны ответы но на ответе нет ни одной оценки (ни одного DV или UV)

То есть цель поднятия вопроса Духом - привлечь к нему внимание, чтобы был выбран правильный ответ плюсами участников (не галкой), или дан новый, за который тоже кто-то проголосует плюсом. Либо вопрос привлечет иное внимание и будет закрыт по флагам/тревогам.

> стоит ли закрывать (выносить на голосование за закрытие/выбор лучшего ответа) данные вопросы,

Если вопрос плохой - ставьте флаг/тревогу. Закрывать вопрос другими способами - незачем.

> и вопрос будет постоянно подниматься в выдаче

Судя по всему не будет, достаточно проголосовать плюсами/минусами.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста "правильный ответ голосами участников". Может ли зеленая галка поставиться голосами участников?

Comment: @Anamnian уточнил

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот [пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736935/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-json-array-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82), который только что был поднят духом. Как видим есть два ответа с положительным рейтингом.

Comment: @Anamnian согласно таймлайнам ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/736939/timeline), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/738658/timeline)) голоса появились только сегодня. Т.е. как раз после поднятия Духом.

Answer (score 1):

Открываю вопрос из примера, перехожу на профиль автора, там вижу

> На сайте 14 дней, из них 1 подряд

То, что вопрос старый, далеко не означает, что автор исчез.

С какой стати закрывать вопрос, я вообще не понимаю.

Надо просто голосовать за имеющиеся ответы или публиковать новые - собственно для этого вопрос и поднимается.

Comment: Поэтому я и написал- "с большой вероятностью". Данное справедливо для данного примера, но на моей памяти был вопрос с сроком давности 5 лет, у которого не было ответа/было несколько ответов, но он продолжал подниматься Духом.

Comment: @Anamnian, из-за того, что у все ответов был нулевой рейтинг. Дух хочет, чтобы что-то оценили (положительно или отрицательно).

Comment: @Qwertiy особенно эпично это выглядит для залоченных вопросов, голосовать по которым нельзя.

Comment: @alexolut, для залоченных надо отдельный баг заводить ;)

Comment: Есть уже такой репорт: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291608/